# How can i create social reader application in facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-interface

i want to create social reader facebook application something like as washington post social reader. but i have no idea about its login and how it work. i have one site which contain daily news updates. so i want social reader application, so if user read ant news from my site then it publish on facebook timeline.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make something like the Washington Post Social Reader?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8014385/how-can-i-make-something-like-the-washington-post-social-reader)

Answer (score 2):

first you need to create a facebook application: 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/

Canvas applications are basicly iframe pages. Mean the main page is hosted in your own website.

then you should read: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/keyconcepts/ to learn what is action and how to use it.

I suggest you to find a facebook api to handle most of the auth. and background stuff.

You need to create a web page for your content and ask for necessary permissions (like publish_stream, publish_actions, email etc) and after that step you can post "x reads y" type actions to users wall.